# Using Optaplanner for VRPPD

Tags: optaplanner

I am trying to run the example "optaplanner-mixedvrp-experiment" developed by Geoffrey De Smet and when I run it it throws me the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The entity (MY) has a
> variable (previousStandstill) with value (MUNO) which has a
> sourceVariableName variable (nextVisit) with a value (WERBOMONT) which
> is not null. Verify the consistency of your input problem for that
> sourceVariableName variable.

I have not made any change, I have only cloned and executed it, I import and solve it and it throws me this error.

Do you know what could be happening?

I am applying it in the development of a variant of VRP with multiple deliveries and collections, but it throws me the same error. I have activated the FULL_ASSERT mode and nextVisit, previousStandstill, visitIndex are always null

Comment: Gloria, did you ever get the example working?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I looked at that code, so it's using an old version of optaplanner. Our goal is still to clean it up and offer an out of the box example for VRPPD (and probably remove some boilerplate along the way, using the upcoming `@CollectionPlanningVariabe` etc). That being said, we have multiple users&customers who used that optaplanner-mixedvrp-experiment to successfully build VRPPD implementations.

Which dataset did you try?

FWIW, that IllegalStateException says that when A.previous = B, the B.next is not A. So either the dataset importer didn't import it correctly - before calling `solve()` - especially if it fails before the first CH step in FULL_ASSERT. Or one of the custom moves corrupted the model.

Comment: cvrp-32customers, cvrp-54customers and cvrp-72customers give me this error of consistency, while the rest give me a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException apparently because of an error in VehicleRoutingSolutionPainter in the lines "TangoColorFactory.SEQUENCE_1.length". But the case is that for my VRPPD variant, from the example I am only reusing the domain and persistence and it throws me the same consistency error relating previousStandstill and nextVisit. Any idea of how I can solve it for my variant?

Comment: I found a description of "optaplanner-mixedvrp-experiment" in Jira PLANNER-833 , where I understand that the example can be reused for "taxi VRP", "airport shuttle VRP" and "mixed heterogeneous...". I understand that my problem can be modeled as "taxi VRP", since I need multipicking where deliveries and pick-ups are mixed, but a delivery point is only visited once. I would ask you: What restriction would you suggest to enforce that condition? But I haven't been able to make any progress since I find myself solving the previous point related to the consistency error.

Comment: A taxi VRP (= normal uber) doesn't need the complexity of mixedpickup-and-delivery. A dial a ride problem (= uber pool) does need it. For a taxi VRP just have a start and end location and service time for each "visit". No need to model pickups and deliveries seperatly, because there are no pickups or deliveries in between the start and end of a single taxi ride.